# Using Angular 2+ forRoot pattern to pass callbacks into modules

Tags: angular, angular2-modules, angular2-providers

I have created an Angular Module called `DataModule` which contains services for accessing my backend through a token-secured HTTP API. On HTTP access control errors such as `401 Unauthorized` and `403 Forbidden` I want to be able to redirect to `/login` or try and refresh the token etc.

I want to re-use this `DataModule` in an Ionic application, so i don't want any coupling with the standard `@angular/router`
 `RouterModule` or anything else.

Currently, I am passing in some primitive values via the forRoot method when importing the `DataModule` in my `AppModule`:

```
DataModule.forRoot({
  url: environment.apiEndpoint,
  token() {
     return localStorage.getItem('auth_token')
  },
  onError(errors: any) {
     console.log(this);
  }
});
```

I need the `onError` callback to have the ability to call `router.navigate('/login')` or similar, but as this is a simple config object I don't think `router` can be injected at this stage.

I am looking for a way to pass something like this in and I have reviewed several other popular ng projects such as `ngx-translate`, `angularitics2` and `ngx-restangular` which all pass in providers that seem to be then provided back by the components. Is this the way to achieve what I am after by passing in an AuthException service or similar that implements an interface kept in the `DataModule` package?

**Update:**

I've ended up taking the idea from the projects I mentioned which is for my `DataModule` to have a default service for error handling which basically does nothing. I then inject a better error handling class that is specific to the app in the forRoot which then gets used in the providers:

```
static forRoot(config: any): ModuleWithProviders {

    return {
      ngModule: DataModule,
      providers: [
        config.authExceptionService || AuthExceptionService,
        { provide: CONFIG, useValue: config },
        {
          provide: ApiService,
          useFactory: ApiServiceFactory,
          deps: [Http, config.authExceptionService || AuthExceptionService, CONFIG]
        },
      ]
    }
  }
```

My `ApiServiceFactory` for reference:

```
export function ApiServiceFactory(http: Http, authException: AuthExceptionService, config: any) {

  return new ApiService(http, authException, {
    url: config.url,
    token: config.token
  });
}
```

I also had to make use of an `InjectionToken` in order to provide my config object as a dependency to the factory:

```
export const CONFIG = new InjectionToken<any>('CONFIG');
```

From my main app I do the following:

```
DataModule.forRoot({
      authExceptionService: AppAuthExceptionService,
      url: environment.apiEndpoint,
      token() {
        return localStorage.getItem('auth_token')
      }
    });
```

It would be great to hear from anyone if there are any potential issues with this approach. I am hoping I should be able to use this module in the Ionic app with something like the following:

```
DataModule.forRoot({
      authExceptionService: MobileAppAuthExceptionService,
      url: environment.apiEndpoint,
      token() {
        return storage.getItem('auth_token') // ionic uses different storage
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `Http` and apply a [filter](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html)

```
export class MyHttp extends Http {
   //... 
   constructor(){super()}

   get(){
      super.get()
        .filter(x => {
         // do your logic here
         if(x.status === 403){
            router.navigate( errorPage )
            return false;
         }             
      })
   }
}
```

Or alternatively use [map](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) and throw an error

```
if (response.status === 403) {
   throw Observable.throw(response);  
 }
```

and have a catch function that does the redirect (which imo is the better way to do it).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for this is to extend your DataModule in each project and override the onError and constructor methods respectively.

```
export class MyDataModule extends DataModule {

  static ForRoot(...){
    ...
  }

  constructor(...args, private router: Router){
    super(...args)
  }

  onError() {
    this.router.navigate(errorPage);
  }
}
```

Then in your ionic application you can handle the error in some other way.